# Implicit conversion when calling an extension method not possible

Tags: c#, roslyn

Why is it not possible to use implicit conversion when calling an extension method?

Here is the sample code:

```
using System;

namespace IntDecimal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal d = 1000m;
            int i = 1000;

            d = i; // implicid conversion works just fine

            Console.WriteLine(d.ToNumberString()); // Works as expected
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToNumberString()); // Error
            Console.WriteLine(ToNumberString2(i)); // Implicid conversion here works just fine
        }

        static string ToNumberString2(decimal d)
        {
            return d.ToString("N0");
        }
    }

    public static class Ext
    {
        public static string ToNumberString(this decimal d)
        {
            return d.ToString("N0");
        }
    }
}
```

Error i get:
'int' does not contain a definition for 'ToNumberString' and the best extension method overload 'Ext.ToNumberString(decimal)' requires a receiver of type 'decimal'

As we can see. An implicit conversion from int to decimal exists and works just fine when we do not use it as an extension method.

I know what I can do to get things working,
**But what is the technical reason that there is no implicit cast possible when working with extension methods?**

Comment: Extensions do not convert. They extend a specific type. [See this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for more info.

Comment: I don't think the compiler was built to call extension methods.  An action like that might be deemed unsafe by the compiler writers.

Comment: You either have to cast it to decimal `((decimal)i).ToNumberString()` or create a new overload for the extension method with an `int`.

Comment: I know what I can do, to get this working, but I want to know the technical reason behind this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be very confusing if you were able to call all methods of all object that the current object has an implicit cast to? What if multiple of them have the same signature?

Comment: @Magnus It picks the best match. That's the case with instance methods.

Comment: @VSDekar I said identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implicit conversions *are* allowed for the target of extension method invocations, but they're restricted. From section 7.5.6.2 of the ECMA C# 5 standard:

> An extension method *Ci.Mj* is eligible if:
>
> - ...
> - An implicit identity, reference or boxing conversion exists from *expr* to the type of the first parameter of *Mj*.

In your case, the conversion involved is not an identity, reference or boxing conversion, so the method is not eligible.

We use eligible mutations almost every time we use LINQ. For example:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
IEnumerable<string> query = names.Select(x => x.ToUpper());
```

Here the target of the method is `IEnumerable<T>`, but the argument type is `List<string>`. `T` is inferred to be `string`, but there's still a conversion required from `List<string>` to `IEnumerable<string>`. That's permitted though, because it's a *reference conversion*.

I can see why the rule exists for reference types, at least. Suppose we had a mutable reference type `X` with an implicit conversion to another mutable reference type `Y`. An extension method targeting `Y` that mutated it would be very confusing, because it would presumably not mutate the original `X`. Extension methods are meant to "feel" like they're acting on the original value, and that isn't the case when conversions other than the ones listed are permitted.

Even boxing conversions feel slightly dubious to me. Here's an example, using a mutable struct that implements an interface:

```
using System;

public interface IMutable
{
    void Mutate();
}

public static class MutationExtensions
{
    public static void CallMutate(this IMutable target)
    {
        target.Mutate();
    }
}

public struct MutableStruct : IMutable
{
    public int value;

    public void Mutate()
    {
        value++;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MutableStruct x = new MutableStruct();
        Console.WriteLine(x.value); // 0
        x.Mutate();
        Console.WriteLine(x.value); // 1
        x.CallMutate();
        Console.WriteLine(x.value); // 1
    }
}
```

That last result (1, not 2) is because the value was boxed to be an `IMutable`, and only the box was modified - not the `x` variable.

I suspect corner cases like this were deemed "acceptably nasty" bearing in mind the benefit of being able to write extension methods for other interfaces that value types might implement, such as `IFormattable`. (Admittedly a generic method with a constraint on the type parameter would probably be a better idea there anyway.)

Comment: Interesting, even though I don't understand it completely. Can you give a sample of an eligible implicit conversion?

Comment: @VSDekar: I've edited the answer - reference conversions are probably the most common here.

Comment: Why can't you get boxing conversions to work? Just define extension on `this object` and call it on `int` - boxing conversion.

Comment: @Evk: In my test program I'd forgotten to add the `this` modifier to the parameter in the extension method :) I've now included the example.

Comment: Thanks for your well written answer. I have learned something today! :-)

Comment: @DaisyShipton Ok... I think I understand now more or less why we cannot use implicit conversion on extension methods. But don't we have the very same problems on instance methods? Why is implicit conversion allowed on instance methods?

Comment: @VSDekar: Only certain implicit conversions are allowed on method call targets, too. For example, there's an implicit conversion from `string` to `XName`, and `XName` has a `Get(string)` instance method - but you can't write `"ns".Get("name")`. It's entirely possible that the set of valid conversions for method call targets *is* the set of valid conversions for extension methods; I'd have to check.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I'm quite sure it is. Reference conversion is in play, for example, when you call method defined in parent class, and boxing - when you, for example, call `ToString()` on struct which does not override it.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Maybe I don't understand everything since English is not my native language, but what is with the static method in my sample `ToNumberString2(decimal d)`? There the implicit conversion is allowed, but I think we face the same problems like we have with extension methods... So i still don't get why implicit conversion is allowed for "normal" methods but not for extension methods.

Comment: @VSDekar: That's an implicit conversion for an *argument* to the method, not for the *target* of the method call. That's the difference. Other implicit conversions are allowed for all but the first parameter of an extension method - but extension methods are meant to "feel" as if you're calling them on that first parameter. Even though really the "target" of the extension method is a regular first argument as far as the CLR is concerned, the language is designed to treat it similarly to targets of instance methods.

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
using System;

namespace IntDecimal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal d = 1000m;
            int i = 1000;

            d = i; // implicid conversion works just fine

            Console.WriteLine(d.ToNumberString()); // Works as expected
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToNumberString()); // Error
            Console.WriteLine(ToNumberString2(i)); // Implicid conversion here works just fine
        }

        static string ToNumberString2(decimal d)
        {
            return d.ToString("N0");
        }
    }

    public static class Ext
    {
        public static string ToNumberString(this decimal d)
        {
            return d.ToString("N0");
        }

        public static string ToNumberString(this int d)
        {
            return d.ToString("N0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not the answer to the question. while technically correct.

Comment: The question is _why_ the compiler does not use the `decimal` extension with an implicit conversion, like it does when using instance methods.